# TFS Integration Tools: Version Control to Version Control - nothing really happens

Tags: tfsintegrationplatform

I've just investigated TFS Integration Tools to migrate all source code along with the history from one TFS server 2010 to another, and I have experienced a strange behaviour. Here are my actions:

1. Installed TFS Server locally.
2. Created two project collections and project in each of them (Source project and Target project).
3. Filled Source project with some files, made several check-outs and check-ins.
4. Launched TFS Integration Tools.
5. Created new configuration with template VersionControl.xml
6. Chosen Source project as a Left Source and Target project as a Right Source.
7. Started the migration. Everything was well, I could see all history in the progress window.

And the result of these actions is the following - nothing changed. Literally. I expected that the source control of the Target project will be filled with files from Source project's ones. But both projects remained exactly as they were.

What am I missing? What have I misunderstood about the TFS Integration Tools?

**Update**

Here is the config that was generated by the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" UniqueId="cdf29df8-c74f-4339-b96f-7eb621c1cee1" FriendlyName="TFS to TFS Version Control">
  <Providers>
    <Provider ReferenceName="febc091f-82a2-449e-aed8-133e5896c47a" FriendlyName="TFS 2010 Migration VC Provider" />
  </Providers>
  <Addins />
  <SessionGroup CreationTime="2011-04-28T11:24:10.9503239Z" FriendlyName="TFS to TFS Version Control" SessionGroupGUID="394da96f-b8b6-4bc1-9b72-1c6234c4b9f1" Creator="<domain>\<user_name>" SyncIntervalInSeconds="0" SyncDurationInMinutes="0">
    <MigrationSources>
      <MigrationSource InternalUniqueId="181ddf3d-9cdb-461a-9dba-4338cf2a02f8" FriendlyName="<server_name> (VC)" ServerIdentifier="c0a0f4e4-4a37-4a89-ba23-fbd323680786" ServerUrl="http://<server_name>:8080/tfs/sourcecollection" SourceIdentifier="SourceProject" ProviderReferenceName="febc091f-82a2-449e-aed8-133e5896c47a" EndpointSystemName="TFS">
        <Settings>
          <Addins />
          <UserIdentityLookup />
          <DefaultUserIdProperty UserIdPropertyName="DisplayName" />
        </Settings>
        <CustomSettings />
        <StoredCredential />
      </MigrationSource>
      <MigrationSource InternalUniqueId="e292262f-9479-490f-b5e3-ce7e845d1468" FriendlyName="<server_name> (VC)" ServerIdentifier="f01ebcec-ea18-4933-b3fd-751740904136" ServerUrl="http://<server_name>:8080/tfs/targetcollection" SourceIdentifier="Target" ProviderReferenceName="febc091f-82a2-449e-aed8-133e5896c47a" EndpointSystemName="TFS">
        <Settings>
          <Addins />
          <UserIdentityLookup />
          <DefaultUserIdProperty UserIdPropertyName="DisplayName" />
        </Settings>
        <CustomSettings />
        <StoredCredential />
      </MigrationSource>
    </MigrationSources>
    <Sessions>
      <Session CreationTime="2011-04-28T11:24:10.9333256Z" SessionUniqueId="4aa097f3-9a01-4924-b562-384215b4ef2f" FriendlyName="Version Control Session" LeftMigrationSourceUniqueId="181ddf3d-9cdb-461a-9dba-4338cf2a02f8" RightMigrationSourceUniqueId="e292262f-9479-490f-b5e3-ce7e845d1468" SessionType="VersionControl">
        <EventSinks />
        <CustomSettings>
          <SettingXml />
          <SettingXmlSchema />
        </CustomSettings>
        <Filters>
          <FilterPair Neglect="false">
            <FilterItem MigrationSourceUniqueId="181ddf3d-9cdb-461a-9dba-4338cf2a02f8" FilterString="$/SourceProject" />
            <FilterItem MigrationSourceUniqueId="e292262f-9479-490f-b5e3-ce7e845d1468" FilterString="$/Target" />
          </FilterPair>
        </Filters>
      </Session>
    </Sessions>
    <Linking>
      <CustomSettings />
      <LinkTypeMappings />
    </Linking>
    <WorkFlowType Frequency="ContinuousManual" DirectionOfFlow="Unidirectional" SyncContext="Disabled" />
    <CustomSettings />
    <UserIdentityMappings EnableValidation="false">
      <UserIdentityLookupAddins />
    </UserIdentityMappings>
    <ErrorManagement>
      <ErrorRouters />
      <ReportingSettings />
    </ErrorManagement>
  </SessionGroup>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct. At very least the target should've had the same as the source. Sounds like the config is wrong and/or something went pear. Can you post the config + log?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated the post with config information. I didn't add the log to avoid littering of the post, but I've review it carefully and found neither errors nor warnings. Moreover, according to the log everything went fine, all change sets were transfered properly.

Comment: Are you doing this on a single server (which is what I suspected from the post) or two servers (which is what your config is set to)?

Comment: Single server. Could you please point out how to set config for this case properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit that this is really strange, but the issue is solved. I haven't done any changes to configuration, but when I've reran the migration everything worked - all source code appeared in Target project source control along with check-ins history. Moreover, I've created another empty Target project and migration worked fine as well. It seems that the problem was caused by some temporary TFS Integration Tools fluctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that looks out is that the value `ServerIdentifier` attribute on the two `MigrationSource`'s is different, as this is a single server deployment they should be the same, can't think of a reason it should matter though - but it is the only thing that I would change.

Everything else in your config is fine.